# CODENAMEONE account email change

Tags: codenameone

I have an account I have used for the past 5 years with codenameone. However I do not have access to this email anymore. I do not want to create a new account as I do have some credits which cannot be transfered.

How can I be assisted with this as I am unable to install the Build app on my phone.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a new account. You can't use Codename One with an email account you no longer own.

Even when we do finally implement the ability to change the email address of an account we will need a way to verify your authority to do it by sending an email to the old account.